# Airflow jdbc unable to find class driver

Tags: airflow

I am unable to set up a jdbc connection in Airflow.  I keep receiving the error class not found.

My connection looks like the following:
[image: airflow_jdbc_conn]

Here is the error i receive in Airflow when testing:
[image: driver_error]

My connection credentials are all correct and I can connect with SQLWorkbenchJ.  Also I have tried different redshift jdbc drivers and class names.

/Users/mkleinert/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:406: DeprecationWarning: Importing PythonOperator directly from  has been deprecated. Please import from '.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
/Users/mkleinert/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:406: DeprecationWarning: Importing MsSqlOperator directly from  has been deprecated. Please import from '.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
/Users/mkleinert/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:406: DeprecationWarning: Importing FTPHook directly from  has been deprecated. Please import from '.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
/Users/mkleinert/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:406: DeprecationWarning: Importing JdbcOperator directly from  has been deprecated. Please import from '.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
/Users/mkleinert/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py:1927: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to JdbcOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'conn_id': 'mssql_etl'}
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the webserver log? Especially when you start it?
Is the jaydebeapi package installed?

(pip install jaydebeapi)

Comment: i checked and jaydepeapi is installed.

Comment: startup logs are pretty clean.  i do have some deprecation warnings but other then that nothing looks out of place.  i added the warnings above.

Comment: It seems that it is quite difficult to make jaydebeapi work with the jdbc/redshift. I usually use the psycopg2 for this. Any reason you are using jdbc?

Comment: I ended up switching to using the postgres connection in Airflow.  I verified it was using psycopg2 to do it's connection.  That is also what we use for all of our other python connections to redshift.  That worked. I will go back and revisit jdbc if I need it in the future.  I am thinking is really just related to my setup, something is off.